# AVR Internal Data bus width

Tags: avr

I got a doubt about the width of internal data bus of AVR controllers connected to flash memory. I was mainly referring to Atmega328. Datasheet says (Page 17) "Since all AVR instructions are 16 or 32 bits wide, the Flash is organized as
2/4/8/16K x 16.". That means flash memory data bus width must be 16 bit? I could not see anywhere mentioning about 16 bit wide program memory data bus (Of course internal to the controller). But bus for RAM seems to be again 8 bit. Just want a clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BitThe 8-bit AVR family is based on a (modified) Harvard architecture, where you have dedicated program and data storages. The data path to program memory is indeed 16-bit, while it is 8-bit only to data memory.

The funny part is, that in the beginning Atmel points out, that these are 8-bit CPUs. This makes them look very competitive when compared to other 8-bit products like 8051 or Rabbit. Due to the 16-bit program data path the AVRs perform very well in benchmark tests. Later, when 8-bit sounds a bit old-fashioned, Atmel decided to call them 8/16-bit CPUs.

Answer (score 2):

Figure 7.1 on page 9 of the [data sheet/complete](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) shows that the flash isn't at all connected to the (8 bit) data bus but only to an address bus. The "data" of the flash memory primarily goes into the instruction register and by use of the `LPM` instruction this data is transferred into a register. Note that when writing data to the flash you always write 16 bit `(R1:R0)` addressed by the `Z` pointer (`SPM` instruction) ... and that the SPM instruction cannot be expressed in "clock cycles" (pg. 617)